# Preprocessor checks for array members

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

These 2 arrays are being modified a lot in the source code, that is why I want the preprocessor to count the number of members in the array. Is it also possible to have the `gcc` `preprocessor` check that array *a* ends in *NULL* and array *b* ends in *0*?

```
static const char *a[] = { "string1", "string2", NULL };

static const int b[] = { 10, 20, 0 };
```

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't know anything about arrays... So I don't think it can check anything like than. You should clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: No, you can't do this using the preprocessor, you have to pay attention. Or even better, require storing the length of the array explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things the preprocessor can do for you, but not quite what you describe. You can determine the number of elements in the array using a macro:

```
#define COUNTOF(arr)  (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*(arr)))
```

then somewhere in a function you can use assert() to test the values:

```
#include <assert.h>
...
... in some function
...

assert(a[COUNTOF(a) - 1] == NULL);
assert(b[COUNTOF(b) - 1] == 0);
```

or something to that effect.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know it could be done with 2 dimensional char arrays.

Comment: @elaine  not sure what you mean by "2 dimensional char arrays". In this case "a" is an array of pointers to characters.